# Upload multiple files each with additional information in spring

Tags: javascript, spring, multiple-file-upload

I'm new to spring boot and js and i'm trying to upload multiple files each having additionl information like description etc.

**Objects :**

```
public class BookDto {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private List<PageDto> pageDtoList;
    // getters setters
}

public class PageDto {
    private String description;
    private MultipartFile file;
    // getters setters
}
```

**Controller :**

```
public class UploadController{

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity createGenre(@RequestBody BookDto bookDto){
       // do something with data
    }
}
```

**Html :**

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple onclick="postRequest(event)">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
function postRequest(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);
    var pageList = [];
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) { 
        pageList.push(new Page( i + "some description",files[i]));
    }
    var newBook = new Book();
    newbook.pageList = pageList;
    book.author = "author1";
    book.title = "title1";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: // i don't really know what to put here,
        url: "/upload",
        success: function (response) {
            // success
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // error
        }
    });

}

function Book(title, author, chapter, pageList){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pageList = pageList;
}

function Page(description, file) {
    this.description = description;
    this.file = file;
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to upload files as described by the objects or do i have to upload them seperately.

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this that way, you need to serialize data, and make a route handling serialized data in order to instanciate matching DTO.

Comment: Could you provide any links/documentation regarding this ? thanks.

Comment: I'll try after lunch but have a look at JSON format it will be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a book instance from a request, considering you have a route such as :

```
@PostMapping("/createBook")
    public ResponseEntity createBook(@RequestBody BookDto bookDto){
       // do something with data
    }
```

you can from client proceed to following :

```
const book = {
   author: "George Orwell",
   title: "1984",
   pageDtoList: []
};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: book,
        url: "/createBook",
        success: function (response) {
            // success
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // error
        }
    });
```

You can then add pages with same logic, but with a file set to null temporary, and upload file after, given a page id.

```
@PostMapping("/addPageToBook")
    public ResponseEntity addPage(@RequestParam("bookid") String bookId, 
                                  @RequestBody PageDto pageDto){

       // add a page instance to your book
    }
```

And after you can set page content :

```
@PostMapping("/setPageContent")
    public ResponseEntity setPage(@RequestParam("bookid") String bookId, 
                                  @RequestParam("pageid") String pageId,
                                  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile content){

       // set content to page, ensure book dto is updated with last page instance
    }
```

You will need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData for AJAX uploading, but maybe (depending on your use case) a simple file input button + submit can be enough.